# compute$\iint_D \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{x}} \ dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is:
$$\iint_D \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{x}} \ dxdy \quad D=y<x^2<2y,\ x<y^2<2x$$

The only thing that i can think of is that maybe change of variable would work but i'm not able to solve it i think that i'm on the wrong path;
I've tried this change of variable:
$$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}, \  v=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}},\quad \iint(\sqrt{u^2+v^2})(\sqrt{xy}) \ dudv$$

Any suggestion would be great, thanks

Comment: I think the fact $ \sqrt{xy} = uv$ would make life simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \iint_D \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{x}} \ dx \ dy \ , \quad D=y<x^2<2y,\ x<y^2<2x$

I would recommend the change of variable as $u = \frac{x^2}{y}, v = \frac{y^2}{x}$.

So, $x = u^{2/3} \ v^{1/3}, \ y = u^{1/3} \ v^{2/3}$

Jacobian is simply $|J| = \frac{1}{3}$

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{3} \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \sqrt{u+v} \, du \, dv$

Answer (score 1):

With your change of variables, you can see that $uv = \sqrt{xy}$. Also, the bounds for the integral are $0<u,v<\sqrt{2}$. As correctly pointed out by MathLover, the Jacobian for this transformation equals $4/3$. Hence the integral becomes

$$ \frac{4}{3}\int_1 ^\sqrt{2} \int_1 ^\sqrt{2} (\sqrt{u^2+v^2})uv \mbox{ d}u\mbox{d}v = \int_1 ^\sqrt{2} \frac{4}{9}v\big( (2 + v^2)^{3/2} - (1+v^2)^{3/2} \big)\mbox{ d}v = \frac{4}{45}((4^{5/2} - 3^{5/2})-(3^{5/2}-2^{5/2}) = \frac{4}{45}(32+4\sqrt{2}-18\sqrt{3}). $$

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Comment: I edited it. Have my upvote!